Use dynamic column names in Spring Data JPA
I am trying to use dynamic column names and values in a query in Spring Data JPA
interface CustomFooRepository {
    fun findByValueIgnoreCase(query: String, type: RequestType): List<Foo>
}

class CustomFooRepositoryImpl(
    @PersistenceContext private val entityManager: EntityManager
) : CustomFooRepository {

    override fun findByValueIgnoreCase(query: String, type: RequestType): List<Foo> {
        val column = when (type) {
            RequestType.first_name -> "first_name"
            RequestType.last_name -> "last_name"
            RequestType.email -> "email"
        }

        val sql = """
            SELECT 
                *,
                SIMILARITY(:column, :query) AS score
            FROM foo
            WHERE :column iLIKE %:query%
            ORDER BY score DESC NULLS LAST, :column
            LIMIT 20;
        """

        val constructedQuery = entityManager.createNativeQuery(sql, Foo::class.java)
        constructedQuery.setParameter("column", column)
        constructedQuery.setParameter("query", query)
        return constructedQuery.resultList as List<Foo>
    }
}


interface FooRepository : JpaRepository<Foo, Long>, CustomFooRepository

But this gives me

org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: No argument for named parameter ':query%'

Why?

WHERE :column ... this is bogus, you can't bind a column name using a prepared statement.

@TimBiegeleisen not sure if I understand. What would be the solution then?

You can not concatenate % inside the query string. It must be concatenate outside.
The best solution is to add a new parameter:
constructedQuery.setParameter("queryWildcard", "%" + query + "%")
So your final sql literal would be:
val sql = """
        SELECT 
            *,
            SIMILARITY(:column, :query) AS score
        FROM foo
        WHERE :column iLIKE :queryWildcard
        ORDER BY score DESC NULLS LAST, :column
        LIMIT 20;
    """


This makes the error go away, but I get an empty result which is wrong.

The original and only problem that you described was the spring error with the wildcard, which is now solved. This new problem has nothing to do with the problem of the post. Now is a problem of your query, try executing the query on the db console, check the similarity function, etc. But now you know how to put wildards in query strings.

You totally can concatenate a parameter with % inside the query itself, you just need to use correct concatenation syntax from the database dialect.
